# How to "unpack" the content of a ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building a `@resultBuilder` in my app. This resultBuilder takes `View`s and returns them in an array. This is necessary because the view which takes the content (`WrappingHStack`) needs it as an array. My current source looks like this:

```swift
@resultBuilder public struct ViewArrayBuilder {
  public static func buildBlock() -> [EmptyView] {
    [EmptyView()]
  }
  
  public static func buildBlock<Content: View>(_ content: Content) -> [AnyView] {
    [AnyView(content)]
  }
}

struct WrappingHStack: View {
  @usableFromInline var alignment: Alignment = .topLeading
  @usableFromInline var spacing: CGFloat = 8.0
  @usableFromInline var maxRows: Int = Int.max
  @usableFromInline let content: [AnyView]
  
  @State private var height: CGFloat = 0

  @usableFromInline init(alignment: Alignment = .topLeading,
                         spacing: CGFloat = 8.0,
                         maxRows: Int = Int.max,
                         content: [AnyView]) {
    self.alignment = alignment
    self.spacing = spacing
    self.maxRows = maxRows
    self.content = content
  }

  
  @inlinable public init(alignment: Alignment = .topLeading,
                         spacing: CGFloat = 8.0,
                         maxRows: Int = Int.max,
                         @ViewArrayBuilder content: () -> [AnyView]) {
    self.init(alignment: alignment, spacing: spacing, maxRows: maxRows, content: content())
  }
}
```

This all works fine if used like so:

```swift
WrappingHStack(maxRows: 2) {
  Text("1")
  Text("2")
  ...
}
```

If used with a `ForEach` in the closure it is recognised as one view and an array with the single `ForEach` is returned. But I want to get the contents of the `ForEach` and put them in the array. I was thinking about checking the type of the content and if a `ForEach` is detected it would be "unpacked".

```swift
public static func buildBlock<Content: View>(_ content: Content) -> [AnyView] {
    // Doesn’t work because of this error message:
    // Protocol 'RandomAccessCollection' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself
    if let forEachContent = content as? ForEach<RandomAccessCollection, Any, Any> {
      return content.data.map({ elem in AnyView(content.content(elem)) })
    }
    
    return [AnyView(content)]
  }
```

But I can’t seem to find a way to correctly ask for the `ForEach` type.
How would this be done? Or are there better ways to "unpack" the content of the `ForEach`?

### Update

Why I need that?

I try to create a "wrapping" `HStack`. That is a view that lays out its children horizontally like a normal `HStack`. Once the available width is used up it wraps the children and continues on the next line. I base my approach on [this article](https://swiftui.diegolavalle.com/posts/linewrapping-stacks).
So at one point in time I do need the views created with the `ForEach` construct to lay them out as I want to. If I were able to correctly cast the `content` parameter of the `buildBlock` method to the `ForEach` type I could use the `content` function of `ForEach` to create the views. Like shown in the code block above.

I’m also open for other suggestions which accomplish the wrapping stack I need. (The lazy grids Apple provides are not what I want. My child views are of different width and I want them to flow like text would within the `WrappingHStack`.)

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: You cannot "unpack" the collection of views, because ForEach does not have them. ForEach contains a collection of data and a _function_ which creates a view from an element.

Comment: I think, you should approach the problem from a different angle. You probably don't need a ViewArrayBuilder. Try to have your data model in such a form which can be used to apply a regular view builder to construct your custom view hierarchy. Otherwise, please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I know that "unpacking" means using the `content` function `ForEach` provides. I also updated the question to explain why I need this.

Comment: Seems like `FlowLayout` is what you're trying to build. Check existing implementations like this one https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/3c6ea3fb2102052d1898d8ea27fbee07 they might inspire you.

Comment: @RayWojciechowski Check out my repo [GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor) - this seems to be exactly what you are looking for. It unpacks `ForEach` too. You can see in the code [here](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor/blob/09cc1e7bf7d1860b92b151bb0bf06ec25a9e9162/Sources/ViewExtractor/ViewExtractor.swift#L88) is what views are checked.

Comment: @eugene-dudnyk This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @George, I will have a deeper look at your suggestions since this seems to be a solution for my original question.

Comment: I read your article you provided in the update. Instead of using a hosting view controller to get the frame of a view, you would rather apply alignment guides to each element view in a (for example) HStack. Basically, you can arbitrarily offset (move) any element view within a Stack by using [alignment guides](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/aligning-views-within-a-stack).

Answer (score 1):

[WrappingHStack](https://github.com/dkk/WrappingHStack) library does the wrapping and can be used as a forEach:

```
WrappingHStack(1...30, id:\.self) {
    Text("Item: \($0)")
}
```